# Can define Property without any Type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I have three models that inherit from the B model, each of which has a property called `Id`, which is different in each type.

```
public class BaseModel
{
    string createTime;
}

public class IntValue:Base
{
    int Id;
}

public class LongValue:Base
{
    long Id;
}

public class ShortValue:Base
{
    short Id;
}
```

Now I want to write a generic function that performs special operations on samples based on these three models. In this operation, I will compare the property `Id` with another parameter defined as the function input. So I had to define three generic functions and make this comparison in each one. Is there a way I can turn these three generic functions into one function ?
Can I define `Id` without any Type in BaseModel?

```
public void Get<T> (List<T> items,List<int> requestItem)where T : IntValue
{
    //Do Something ...

    items.where(x=> requestItem.Contains(x.id))

    //Do Something ...
}


public void Get<T> (List<T> items,List<long> requestItem)where T : LongValue
{
    //Do Something ...

    items.where(x=> requestItem.Contains(x.id))

    //Do Something ...
}

public void Get<T> (List<T> items,List<short> requestItem)where T : ShortValue
{
    //Do Something ...

    items.where(x=> requestItem.Contains(x.id))

    //Do Something ...
}
```

Comment: You can make `BaseModel` generic (`BaseModel<T>`) and create a property `Id` of type `T`

Comment: So How can I Handle this `items.where(x=> requestItem.Contains(x.id))` can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do something like:

```cs
public class BaseModel<T>
{
    string createTime;
    T Id;

    public void Get (List<T> items, List<T> requestItem)
    {
        //Do Something ...

        items.where(x => requestItem.Contains(x.id))

        //Do Something ...
    }
}
```

Then you would only have to inherit `BaseModel` with the right generic argument:

```cs
public class ShortValue: BaseModel<short>
{
}
```

Be aware that this may not work for non-value types and `IEqualityComparer<T>` or any other comparison strategy would be needed.